# Paypal add custom_id directly in order url

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

Can I attach custom_id to paypal order link like that (&custom_id=${customId})? Or in order to add custom_id I MUST use **paypal-js**?

`https://www.paypal.com/webapps/billing/plans/subscribe?plan_id=${plan_d}&custom_id=${customId}`

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be added to a URL, you need to create the subscription for every checkout attempt.

You can create the subscription using the JS SDK, which gives the best in-context approval flow (not redirecting away from your website, keeping it loaded in the background) -- or you can do so with the REST API and get a link for approval, which is an older flow.

Comment: Hm, How to do it with REST API?

Comment: Using the create subscription API call https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create